# Pass a variable to Spark DF lit function

Tags: python, dataframe, pyspark

I am trying to add a new column to an existing spark df. If I specify the df column name as the new value for the new column than it works, but since i want the value column to be dynamic based on configs i want to pass the value from a variable.

e.g:

```
>>> df1.printSchema()
root
 |-- COL_A: string (nullable = true)
 |-- COL_B: string (nullable = true)
 |-- COL_C: string (nullable = true)
```

if I use `df2 = df1.withColumn("COL_D", lit(df1.COL_A))` then it works as expected.
However if i have variable and try to pass that than it does not work.

```
val_col = "COL_B"
```

`df2 = df1.withColumn("COL_D", lit(df1.val_col))`

I am not sure if this is even possible, but wanted to ask .Let me know if anyone has done similar thing before.

Answer (score 1):

Use `col` function to avoid this issue.

```
df = sqlContext.createDataFrame([(1,'Björn'),(2,'Oliver'),(3,'Müller')],['ID','Name']) 
df.show() 
+---+------+
| ID|  Name|
+---+------+
|  1| Björn|
|  2|Oliver|
|  3|Müller|
+---+------+                                  
df1 = df.withColumn('New_ID',lit(df.ID))
df1.show()
+---+------+------+
| ID|  Name|New_ID|
+---+------+------+
|  1| Björn|     1|
|  2|Oliver|     2|
|  3|Müller|     3|
+---+------+------+
```

*So far so good.* But, the moment we assign a column name to a variable, we get an error, as demonstrated below -

```
val_col = "ID"
df1 = df.withColumn('New_ID',lit(df.val_col))

AttributeErrorTraceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-48-1bb287cfa9f2> in <module>
      5 
      6 val_col = "ID"
----> 7 df1 = df.withColumn('New_ID',lit(df.val_col))
      8 
      9 from pyspark.sql.functions import col

/opt/mapr/spark/spark-2.2.1/python/pyspark/sql/dataframe.py in __getattr__(self, name)
   1018         if name not in self.columns:
   1019             raise AttributeError(
-> 1020                 "'%s' object has no attribute '%s'" % (self.__class__.__name__, name))
   1021         jc = self._jdf.apply(name)
   1022         return Column(jc)

AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'val_col'
```

You get this error because there is no variable named `val_col`, and Python assumes what follows after the dot as a column name. It doesn't take string per-se.

**Solution:** You can avoid this issue all together by importing `col` function and using it to do your operations.

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import col
val_col = "ID"
df1 = df.withColumn('New_ID',lit(col(val_col)))
df1.show()
+---+------+------+
| ID|  Name|New_ID|
+---+------+------+
|  1| Björn|     1|
|  2|Oliver|     2|
|  3|Müller|     3|
+---+------+------+
```

Comment: I get the following error: `AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute '_get_object_id'` what does it mean?